# Device /dev/fuse for a container running Rancher in Mac

Tags: mac-osx, containers, fuse, rancher

I'm trying to test in my corporate Mac runnning Ventura 13.5.2 the new container Oracle Autonomous Database
I'm running Rancher 1.10.0

I'm following the instructions in

https://github.com/oracle/adb-free/pkgs/container/adb-free

As indicate in a note, for OFS mount, container should start with SYS_ADMIN capability. Also, virtual device /dev/fuse should be accessible

But in MacOS fuse is not installed by default.

So, I have installed with
`brew install fuse`

But, even after correct install, I'm not able to see the `/dev/fuse` device.

As reference, I remind the configuration file:

```
docker run -d \
-p 1521:1522 \
-p 1522:1522 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 27017:27017 \
--hostname localhost \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
--device /dev/fuse \
--name adb_container \
ghcr.io/oracle/adb-free:latest
```

Any suggestion?